# How to retrieve the Ki value of sim card?

Tags: gsm

I was wondering is there any way to catch the Ki value in the SIM card by any coding? Is there a tool for that?

NOTE: Ki, only exist in SIM (Mobile Station) and BSC database. It won't be transmitted in network.

Comment: This depends on the card. You may want to look into SIM cloning techniques.